# Parsing a subroutine and determining arguments of function call in perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm writing a perl script which needs to parse a file (or more specifically, a known sub in the file) find a specific function call, and retrieve all the arguments for that call.  For example:

```
sub MySub {
    # some code here...
    # ...

    MyFunction ([q{I}, q{want}], [qw(to get)], 
        ["these", "arguments"]);

    # ...
    # more code...
}
```

I've been able to parse through the file grab the appropriate line/lines for the function call, and then I wrote my own local "MyFunction" which can grab the args.  Then I use a stringy eval to call that function and get the arguments.  Example:

```
sub MyFunction {
    return @_;
}

# Not actually doing this, but this is what I might get from parsing:
my $lines = 'MyFunction ({arg1 => "hashref"}, ["arg2", "arrayref"], "etc...");';

my @arguments = eval $lines;
```

This works great, except for the fact that I'm using a [stringy eval](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic-1.126/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/BuiltinFunctions/ProhibitStringyEval.pm).  The problem with parsing the argument directly out of the string is there are many different formats (including multiple lines) that are possible.  So I guess is there an easy way to parse the arguments directly out of the string, or to call the function without a stringy eval?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? It seems like it might be easier to import the other module.

Comment: If your major reason for wanting not to do this, is because `perlcritic` complains, I would suggest that the answer is turn off that warning - a "stringy eval" is _exactly_ what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Sobrique Because of the way the codebase is set up, there would be some hoops to jump through to do that.  But it is possible if that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to eval if you don't want to. You can use the name to get the symbol and then use that to get the code ref.

```
my $func = do { 
    no strict 'refs';
    *{'main::MyFunction'}{CODE};
};

my @arguments = $func->( {arg1 => "hashref"}, ["arg2", "arrayref"], "etc..." );
```

Comment: So the point of the question was that all the arguments were stored in a string and I want to extract them.  I don't have them as actual perl structures.

Answer (score -1):

Parsing Perl is hard (and there's a folk theorem that only Perl can parse Perl).   Parsing perl with your own hand-rolled string hack is likely to end in disaster in all but the simplest cases.     What you really want is a tool that can parse Perl and give you the arguments.

Our DMS Software Reegineering Toolkit can do this.  See parse tree below,
obtained from a file that contains exactly OP's MySub example text:

```
C:\DMS\Domains\Perl\Tools\Parser>run ..\domainparser ++AST C:\temp\test.pl

Perl~Perl5 Domain Parser Version 2.6.15 DEBUG BUILD
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 Semantic Designs, Inc; All Rights Reserved; SD Confidential
Powered by DMS (R) Software Reengineering Toolkit
Using encoding Unicode-UTF-8?ANSI +CRLF +1 /^I
432 tree nodes in tree.
(Perl@Perl~Perl5=1#5c21d20^0 Line 1 Column 1 File C:/temp/test.pl
 (statements@Perl~Perl5=10#5c21c80^1#5c21d20:1 Line 1 Column 1 File C:/temp/test.pl
  (subroutine_head@Perl~Perl5=551#5c73680^1#5c21c80:1 Line 1 Column 1 File C:/temp/test.pl
   (IDENTIFIER@Perl~Perl5=573#5c735e0^1#5c73680:1[`MySub'] Line 1 Column 5 File C:/temp/test.pl)IDENTIFIER
   (prototype@Perl~Perl5=552#5c73640^1#5c73680:2 Line 1 Column 11 File C:/temp/test.pl)prototype
   (attributes@Perl~Perl5=554#5c73660^1#5c73680:3 Line 1 Column 11 File C:/temp/test.pl)attributes
  )subroutine_head#5c73680
  (block@Perl~Perl5=4#5c21640^1#5c21c80:2 Line 1 Column 11 File C:/temp/test.pl
   precomment 3:1 `# ...'
   precomment 3:2 `# more code...'
   (statement@Perl~Perl5=21#5c7cf40^1#5c21640:1 Line 5 Column 5 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |(call_statement@Perl~Perl5=561#5c209a0^1#5c7cf40:1 Line 5 Column 5 File C:/temp/test.pl
   | (IDENTIFIER@Perl~Perl5=573#5c73920^13#5c210a0:1#5c73ec0:1#5c778c0:1#5c21080:1#5c73e00:1#5c77860:1#5c209a0:1#5c7f860:1#5c73d60:1#5c77840:1#5c7f840:1#5c73560:1#5c777e0:1[`MyFunction'] Line 5 Column 5 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |  precomment 0:1 `# some code here...'
   |  precomment 0:2 `# ...')IDENTIFIER
   | (L20@Perl~Perl5=514#5c7f240^3#5c206c0:2#5c209a0:2#5c21020:1 Line 5 Column 17 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |  (L20@Perl~Perl5=514#5c7b540^3#5c7f240:1#5c7c640:1#5c738e0:1 Line 5 Column 17 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   (L1_term@Perl~Perl5=187#5c7a700^11#5c7abc0:1#5c7b540:1#5c7c860:1#5c7d280:1#5c7b620:1#5c7ad60:1#5c7a9a0:1#5c20840:1#5c7c1c0:1#5c7b8a0:1#5c7aaa0:1 Line 5 Column 17 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   |(L20@Perl~Perl5=514#5c77da0^2#5c7a700:1#5c7a380:2 Line 5 Column 18 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   | (constant@Perl~Perl5=101#5c73180^6#5c77bc0:1#5c77da0:1#5c77d60:1#5c77a00:1#5c7a420:1#5c77ae0:1 Line 5 Column 18 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   |  (string_prefix@Perl~Perl5=120#5c731a0^1#5c73180:1 Line 5 Column 18 File C:/temp/test.pl)string_prefix
   |   |  (ORDINARY_STRING@Perl~Perl5=604#5c77400^1#5c73180:2[`I'] Line 5 Column 19 File C:/temp/test.pl)ORDINARY_STRING
   |   | )constant#5c73180
   |   | (constant@Perl~Perl5=101#5c77e00^6#5c7a6a0:2#5c7a740:2#5c7a2a0:2#5c7a160:2#5c77da0:2#5c7a140:2 Line 5 Column 24 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   |  (string_prefix@Perl~Perl5=120#5c7a020^1#5c77e00:1 Line 5 Column 24 File C:/temp/test.pl)string_prefix
   |   |  (ORDINARY_STRING@Perl~Perl5=604#5c7a000^1#5c77e00:2[`want'] Line 5 Column 25 File C:/temp/test.pl)ORDINARY_STRING
   |   | )constant#5c77e00
   |   |)L20#5c77da0
   |   )L1_term#5c7a700
   |   (L1_term@Perl~Perl5=187#5c7b420^14#5c7b600:2#5c7b780:2#5c7b620:2#5c7c7c0:1#5c7e880:1#5c20600:1#5c7d160:1#5c7c0c0:1#5c7bf00:2#5c7bf80:2#5c20c20:1#5c7c360:1#5c7b540:2#5c7b560:2 Line 5 Column 34 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   |(qw_constant@Perl~Perl5=113#5c7b260^1#5c7b420:1 Line 5 Column 35 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   | (WORD_LIST_STRING_START@Perl~Perl5=630#5c7b180^1#5c7b260:1["("] Line 5 Column 37 File C:/temp/test.pl)WORD_LIST_STRING_START
   |   | (word_list@Perl~Perl5=117#5c7b240^1#5c7b260:2 Line 5 Column 38 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   |  (word_list@Perl~Perl5=117#5c7b200^1#5c7b240:1 Line 5 Column 38 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   |   (word_list@Perl~Perl5=116#5c7b1c0^1#5c7b200:1 Line 5 Column 38 File C:/temp/test.pl)word_list
   |   |   (WORD@Perl~Perl5=633#5c7b1a0^1#5c7b200:2[`to'] Line 5 Column 38 File C:/temp/test.pl)WORD
   |   |  )word_list#5c7b200
   |   |  (WORD@Perl~Perl5=633#5c7b1e0^1#5c7b240:2[`get'] Line 5 Column 41 File C:/temp/test.pl)WORD
   |   | )word_list#5c7b240
   |   | (STRING_END@Perl~Perl5=620#5c7b220^1#5c7b260:3[")"] Line 5 Column 44 File C:/temp/test.pl)STRING_END
   |   |)qw_constant#5c7b260
   |   )L1_term#5c7b420
   |  )L20#5c7b540
   |  (L1_term@Perl~Perl5=187#5c20260^12#5c20e80:2#5c20ea0:2#5c20f20:2#5c20f60:2#5c205c0:2#5c20600:2#5c20620:2#5c20380:2#5c7f240:2#5c7f260:2#5c7e880:2#5c7e8a0:2 Line 6 Column 9 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   (L20@Perl~Perl5=514#5c7e7e0^1#5c20260:1 Line 6 Column 10 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   |(constant@Perl~Perl5=103#5c7d820^5#5c7de60:1#5c7e7e0:1#5c7e140:1#5c7f940:1#5c7dd60:1 Line 6 Column 10 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   | (INTERPOLATED_STRING_START@Perl~Perl5=621#5c7d5e0^2#5c7d840:1#5c7d820:1["""] Line 6 Column 10 File C:/temp/test.pl)INTERPOLATED_STRING_START
   |   | (interpolated_string_content@Perl~Perl5=130#5c7d800^2#5c7d840:2#5c7d820:2 Line 6 Column 11 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   |  (interpolated_string_content@Perl~Perl5=129#5c7d7c0^1#5c7d800:1 Line 6 Column 11 File C:/temp/test.pl)interpolated_string_content
   |   |  (ORDINARY_INTERPOLATED_STRING_CONTENT@Perl~Perl5=642#5c7c6e0^1#5c7d800:2[`these'] Line 6 Column 11 File C:/temp/test.pl)ORDINARY_INTERPOLATED_STRING_CONTENT
   |   | )interpolated_string_content#5c7d800
   |   | (STRING_END@Perl~Perl5=620#5c7d7e0^2#5c7d840:3#5c7d820:3["""] Line 6 Column 16 File C:/temp/test.pl)STRING_END
   |   |)constant#5c7d820
   |   |(constant@Perl~Perl5=103#5c7dc40^3#5c7e7e0:2#5c7e840:2#5c7e8e0:2 Line 6 Column 19 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   | (INTERPOLATED_STRING_START@Perl~Perl5=621#5c76320^4#5c7dec0:1#5c7e420:1#5c7e400:1#5c7dc40:1["""] Line 6 Column 19 File C:/temp/test.pl)INTERPOLATED_STRING_START
   |   | (interpolated_string_content@Perl~Perl5=130#5c76800^4#5c7dec0:2#5c7e420:2#5c7e400:2#5c7dc40:2 Line 6 Column 20 File C:/temp/test.pl
   |   |  (interpolated_string_content@Perl~Perl5=129#5c76140^1#5c76800:1 Line 6 Column 20 File C:/temp/test.pl)interpolated_string_content
   |   |  (ORDINARY_INTERPOLATED_STRING_CONTENT@Perl~Perl5=642#5c76120^1#5c76800:2[`arguments'] Line 6 Column 20 File C:/temp/test.pl)ORDINARY_INTERPOLATED_STRING_CONTENT
   |   | )interpolated_string_content#5c76800
   |   | (STRING_END@Perl~Perl5=620#5c76180^4#5c7dec0:3#5c7e420:3#5c7e400:3#5c7dc40:3["""] Line 6 Column 29 File C:/temp/test.pl)STRING_END
   |   |)constant#5c7dc40
   |   )L20#5c7e7e0
   |  )L1_term#5c20260
   | )L20#5c7f240
   |)call_statement#5c209a0
   )statement#5c7cf40
  )block#5c21640
 )statements#5c21c80
)Perl#5c21d20
```

You still have to walk over the parse tree and pick out the arguments.  If you do pick up subtrees, they can be prettyprinted to generate the surface syntax string.